# htaccess Default Query String Value

Tags: .htaccess

For some reason my `.htaccess` is adding default value for `_url` key.

My .htaccess

```
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
DirectoryIndex index.php
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?_url=/$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

When I visit my project on `http://localhost/my-project` and dump the query string `var_dump($_GET);` I get following result;

```
array(1) {
  ["_url"]=>
  string(11) "/index.html"
}
```

When I visit my project on `http://localhost/my-project/test` and dump the query string, I get following result;

```
array(1) {
  ["_url"]=>
  string(11) "/test"
}
```

I'm guessing it has something to do with my .htaccess and / or server (apache) configuration.

Is there any work around for this issue? Why don't I have expected result;

```
array(1) {
  ["_url"]=>
  string(11) "/"
}
```

Where does this `index.html` comes from and how do I get rid off it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That `index.html` is coming due to your `DirectoryIndex` directive which is probably set to:

```
DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
```

When you visit `http://localhost/my-project` Apache loads `http://localhost/my-project/index.html` due to this directive and your `REQUEST_URI` becomes `index.html` (in current directory).

When `RewriteRule` runs it just passes current URI as GET parameter hence you get `index.html` in `_url` GET parameter.

You can tweak your rules like this:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?_url=/$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Now this rewrite rule won't be invoked for `http://localhost/my-project` since it is matching `.+` pattern.

Comment: Sorry, I added full `.htaccess` code now. I had `DirectoryIndex index.php` and it doesn't work.

Scratch that! It works. I had this `.htaccess` file under another folder. I had to add `DirectoryIndex index.php` to the parent directory's `.htaccess` file and it works!

Thanks a lot.